# Send user to other page on input

Tags: php

I have a pege (index.php) with some text and a form with a single text input field. What i want is for the user to be sent to another page, upload.php if the input is "upload" or browse.php if input is "browse" and so on, how can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: what type of input are you using - textfield, list, ...?

Comment: exactly, textfield input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use header() to send a location header depending on the value of the input.

```
switch ((string) $_POST ['mode'])
{
    case 'browse':
    case 'upload':
        // Redirect
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/' . $_POST ['mode'] . '.php');
        die ();
    break;
    default:
        // invalid input
    break;
}

<form action=<?php echo ($_SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>
    <select name="mode">
        <option value="">select...</option>
        <option value="upload">Upload something</option>
        <option value="browse">Browse files</option>
        <input type="submit" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm trying this method but i'm having a litte trouble understanding your form, please be patient as i am quite new to both html and php. My form looks like this:                                               `<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="inputx">
    </form>`

Comment: He dint asked as specific for php... He just asked "What i want is for the user to be sent to another page"

Comment: @ShivamS.Kara The question is tagged php but not javascript.  Therefore he wanted a PHP solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$page=$_POST['txtpage'];
$redirect=$page.'.php';

if(file_exists($redirect))
{
 header('Location:'.$redirect);
}

?>
```

Comment: txtpage will be upload or browse.this is true

Answer (score -1):

if you want redirect on another page when blur this textfield

```
<input onblur="window.location.href='YOUR_URL?value='+this.value" />
```

if you want redirect on another page when keyup on this textfield

```
<input onkeyup="window.location.href='YOUR_URL?value='+this.value" />
```

This will work for you

Comment: OP asked for a PHP solution.  A javascript solution won't work if javascript is unavailable, and using on* for attaching events is considered pretty obsolete anyway because you can only attach one handler per event that way.